# Python - Get a list of URLs from a complicated html file for scraping purposes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and could not get the list of URLs in the 'a' tags from this website: http://www.tauntondevelopment.org//msip/JHRindex.htm. All I get is an empty list-   clients list: []
Thank you for your help!

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# This is the url of one major industrial park that we will be scraping
park_url = "http://www.tauntondevelopment.org//msip/JHRindex.htm"

uPark = uReq(park_url)
park_html = uPark.read()
uPark.close()

park_soup = soup(park_html, "html.parser")

filename = "ParkText.html"
f = open(filename, "w") 
f.write(park_soup.prettify())
f.close()

# get a list of the urls of park_url    
clients_list = []
for link in park_soup.findAll('li'):
    clients_list.append(link.get('href'))

print("clients list:", clients_list)

# write clients to a file 
filename = "taunton_JHR.csv"

f = open(filename, "w") # 
headers = "Name, Email, Address\n"
f.write(headers)
 
for client_url in clients_list:
    # call the function to scrape the individual park data
    client_url = "http://www.tauntondevelopment.org/msip/" + client_url
    try: 
        uClient = uReq(client_url)
    except:
        print("Error: Unable to open url")
        continue # continue to the next client_url in the list

    client_name, client_email, client_address = scrapeIndPark(uClient)
    
    f.write(client_name  + "," + client_email + "," + client_address + "\n")
    
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to look into html you downloading?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   John Hancock Road
  </title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
 </head>
 <frameset bordercolor="#E0E0E0" cols="25%,591*">
  <frame name="index" src="JHRleft.htm" target="content"/>
  <frame name="content" src="JHRright.htm"/>
 </frameset>
 <noframes>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  </body>
 </noframes>
 <frameset>
 </frameset>
</html>
```

Notice that (at least in my case) it's empty! It's because page is builded with frames. To access frame you need to go to page, run network inspector, go to **network** tab and see url the latter requests (filling the frames with data) are sent. In that case the url you searching for is probably http://www.tauntondevelopment.org//msip/JHRleft.htm

Comment: You're right! that's the root cause of my problem. Thank you for the info on the frames concept :-). Using both of your answers (kosciej16) & João A. Veiga's, I was able to generate the list. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're trying to get the href attribute from the li elements themselves. Actually the li element has a nested p with a nested b which has a nested  inside, you need to get that nested a.

Here is a suggestion:

```
clients_list = []
for link in park_soup.findAll('li'):
    href_attr = link.findAll('p')[0].findAll('b')[0].findAll('a').get('href')
    clients_list.append(href_attr)
```

Another ideia would be to go straight for all a tags:

```
clients_list = []
for link in park_soup.findAll('a'):
    href_attr = link.get('href')
    clients_list.append(href_attr)
```

Comment: Actually I think it's that's not the root case, look at my answer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, both scripts are returning an empty list!